# Inno Setup's installer doesn't require admin rights after uploading and downloading cycle

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, inno-setup, elevated-privileges

I have my Unity game downloading new version of installer from server to `AppData/LocalLow/MyProject/Temp` and trying to run it. Source executable file really requires UAC to run as admin, as it supposed.

```
PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

But when I upload installer to server and download it, an error occurs with a message "Unable to create temp folder. Access denied".

[FC says it is complete copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TAlg.png), but one is requesting permission - another does not.

I upload file by converting to `byte[]` and sending it via `POST`, download - `GET` vice versa

It also happens when I try to run this executable by myself. It just doesn't want to ask me for rights.

---

Also, as solution, I tried to force my game to run new process with admin rights:

If I use Mono, I can run installer's process via :

```cs
new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
         Verb = "runas", 
         FileName = Updater.GetPathToInstaller()
    }
}.Start();
```

But I need to use IL2CPP, and Unity's IL2CPP doesn't include `System.Diagnostics.Process` yet, so I'm using [this solution](https://github.com/josh4364/IL2cppStartProcess) to run my installer.

And I don't know how to force it to run with admin.

---

Manifest of the installer:

```xml
я╗┐<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity name="JR.Inno.Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32"></assemblyIdentity>
<description>Inno Setup</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS>
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"></supportedOS>
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"></supportedOS>
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"></supportedOS>
    </application>
</compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Manifest of "Copy" is identical

Comment: So your installer works. But if you download the same installer from internet to the same machine and run it same way as the original one using the same local account, it produces the error. Is that correct?

Comment: You're approaching it the wrong way. Instead of using "runas", you should manifest your installer with a UAC manifest that says it requires admin privileges.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yep, you got it right. It produces an error because it does not request admin rights. Of course I can use RMB -> Run as Admin, but this it is not the solution for my problem

Comment: @Sunius I think manifest is automaticly generated by Inno Setup and it requires admin rights because of `PrivilegesRequired=admin` string in IS script

Comment: It looks like Inno Setup's manifest gets corrupted after uploading and downloading again

Comment: Indeed, the manifest is there automatically. If the file is binary equivalent, then the manifest is equivalent as well. What version of Inno Setup are you using? Show us log files from both scenarios. Also check downloaded file properties in File Explorer (Security tab). The file can be in a blocked state after downloading from the internet (particularly if you are using some of Microsoft browsers).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am using Inno Setup Compiler 6.0.3. Also I find out that "copy" has low Mandatory Integrity Control (MIC)

Comment: I would expect that this is due to the way the binary downloaded from the Internet is treated by Windows. Your OS probably has some tightened security settings. Talk to the Administrator. Is your installer signed?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, installer is not signed. And targets of our project are schools, so most likely we will face the same OS security setups as ours

Comment: These days an [installer must be signed by EV certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/222140/43677), if you want it to be downloadable from the internet without problems.

Comment: Can you try extracting the manifest out of the installer exe by using "mt.exe -inputresource:<installer_path>.exe;#1 -out:extracted.manifest" and post its contents here?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Inno Setup manifest. It works for everyone. It's fixed. No way you could have messed it for your particular installer.

Comment: "<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
        </requestedPrivileges>" - this is a problem if you want to run it as admin. It should be changed to "requireAdministrator" instead of "asInvoker".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured out that my problem is caused by LOW Integrety Level set to installer after I download it. Why? Because I downloaded it in `Application.persistantDataPath` which is `LocalLow` folder. I changed download folder to `Application.dataPath` which isn't persistent, and in my testing scenario was on the Desktop, and it worked fine - downloaded copy of installer hasn't low MIC

Of course I still need to sign up my installer, as @MartinPrikryl mentioned in the comments, to avoid problems with smart screen, but it isn't the solution for my "It doesn't request the permission, but still needs it" problem

Comment: Downloading stuff to dataPath is a bad idea because you won't necessarily have write access depending where your game gets installed. For instance, Program Files folder is not writable by ordinary applications.

If you go this route, at least pick a folder that will always be writable.